# discord.js bot reacts several times on the action. sends multiple messages to the server using discord.js library

Tags: node.js, discord.js, duplicates

So my code, everytime the thread created in a specific forum, it adds the tag:

```
client.on('threadCreate', (thread) => { 
    if (thread.parentId == global.disrequestforum) {
        const tags = thread.appliedTags.map(tagId => {
            const tag = thread.parent.availableTags.find(t => t.id === tagId);
            return tag ? tag.name : "Unknown";
        });
        let messageText = "Tags:";
        if (tags.includes("Accounting")) {
            messageText = messageText + ' <@' + userid + '>';
        }
        thread.send(messageText);
    }
});
```

Problem is that when you create a post on a forum, it sends to you like 4 messages with same context.

It also applies to **voiceStateUpdate** - I've put notification if someone joins or leaves voice channel, I received message four times per each action (now three, as I've turned this notification off).

On the image you can see those changes.

I've already numerous times updated the bot's token, removed and added back the **js** file to **pm2**. Even restarted the server - it worked for short period of time.

When I edit the code, for example, I write "Tagus" instead of "Tags to messageText variable, it sends three messages with "Tags" and one with updated "Tagus".
So I assume that it somewhere caches the file code and runs it in the background. But where and how - idk. I don't run the script file elsewhere, I've seen some problem similar problem, but nothing helped me.

I can add `if (message.author.bot) {  return; }`, but it won't help with those duplicates, and I've added script that bet creates those posts itself, so I need those tags to be added to all posts on that forum.

I even renamed the **js** file. reuploaded to server, deleted old one, and result is the same...

And it's not the multiple actions that were sent by discord to my server - I've removed script from **pm2**, added **console.log** command and run script using node command - in this case I received 4 messages in discord and only one message in the console.
So, either I can't find the issue, or it might be the library issue itself, like [people had here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2655).

Answer (score 0):

There are two main reasons for this.

1. You have multiple instances of the bot running.
   Check that you only have 1 terminal instance running the bot and that it is not being hosted anywhere else. For example, on a VPS in the cloud.
2. This one is probably your fix, just add a return in the end to stop the function.

```js
client.on('threadCreate', (thread) => { 
    if (thread.parentId == global.disrequestforum) {
        const tags = thread.appliedTags.map(tagId => {
            const tag = thread.parent.availableTags.find(t => t.id === tagId);
            return tag ? tag.name : "Unknown";
        });
        let messageText = "Tags:";
        if (tags.includes("Accounting")) {
            messageText = messageText + ' <@' + userid + '>';
        }
        thread.send(messageText);

        return
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll try the return, thanks. but there is only one instance of the terminal. because there are other scripts that hosted on the same server through the same server, same pm2.

Comment: @KostyaMaers I see, so we can rule out the instance reason and as long as the other pm2 instances do not have the same bot token, they won't interfere.

So that probably just leaves the missing return statement.

Comment: nope.... sadly. return didn't help. we even moved to a different server recently. idk why it might happen. anyway, thank you for answer.

Comment: Hmm, try adding a return in the `tags.includes` `if` statement.

Comment: i would, but I have several of these ifs, so it accumulates tags depending on which topic was created.

Comment: Anyway, the return after the function didn't help... it just sends 4 instances at a time. IDK why. We changed the server, removed the bot... I didn't launch the bot several times on other places...

Comment: This seems like a bug with DiscordJS. Try asking in their GitHub.

Comment: One final thing I suggest is that you reset your token and update it in your app and see if that fixes it.

Comment: token was updated several times... Thanks, will write there.